# updateprogress doesn't show if click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updateprogress

my question in a nutshell is: how not to fire when clicking a button but when the page is completely to loaded?

when I click a link in masterpage, it should show a report in content page.
I've put a updateProgress to show "please wait",  so I put a button in content page which when onclick, its fill the report with a repeater which is in updatepanel linked with updateProgress

so clicking the button works, it shows "please wait" and the report
but I don't want to click the button, I want to fire it automatically, so I've put

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var bouton = document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>').click(); 
        }
    </script>
```

that works like 1 time out of 10.

I would like to know how  to fire the report filling and so show the updateprogress automatically after page is loaded.

Comment: Your question is extremely hard to understand.

Comment: If I understood correctly, what is the need of firing click on page load. Simply load the function on page load. And call that function on button onclick also.